# I dont know why but only my middle element remains unsorted

Tags: java, arrays, quicksort

For some reason the middle element of my array remains unsorted...

```
public class QuickSort {

    public int a[];

    public QuickSort(int[] a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    private void swap(int pos1, int pos2) {
        int t = a[pos1];
        a[pos1] = a[pos2];
        a[pos2] = t;
    }

    private int partition(int low, int high) {
        int i = low, j = low + 1, pivot = low;
        while (j < high) {
            if (a[j] <= a[pivot]) {
                swap(++i, j);
            }
            j++;
        }
        swap(i, pivot);
        return i;
    }

    private void sort(int low, int high) {
        int i;
        if (low >= high)
            return;
        else {
            i = partition(low, high);
            sort(i + 1, high);
            sort(low, i - 1);
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        for (int i : a) {
            sb.append(i);
            sb.append("\n");
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static int[] generateRandomNumbers(int s) {

        int a[] = new int[s];

        for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
            a[i] = new Random().nextInt(50);
        }

        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the size of elements");
        int s = sc.nextInt();

        QuickSort obj = new QuickSort(generateRandomNumbers(s));

        System.out.println(obj.toString());

        obj.sort(0, s - 1);

        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println(obj.toString());
    }

}
```

The array is filled with randomly generated numbers, this is a standard quicksort algorithm
any help would be appreciated , i'm a novice programmer and have tried to debug this code for far too long...

Comment: Can you give an example of an array that you're using this with and the output?

Comment: I am randomly generating the array...ill edit my question to add the entire code...

Comment: Your pivot is the first element. Shouldn't it be more in the middle?

Comment: That should not matter...the pivot can be anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify

```
swap(i+1, pivot);
return i+1;
```

and

```
int i = low-1, j = low, pivot = high;
```

also

```
if (low < high)
        {
            i = partition(low, high);
            sort(i + 1, high);
            sort(low, i - 1);
        }
```

works flawlessly after these changes.

Comment: No problem always happy to help novice programmers like my self. Mark as answer if that solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Or just change the '<' to '<=' as its not checking the high element...

```
 while (j <= high) {
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I cant believe i made such a silly error...sorry for not upvoting , my reputation is too low...

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake....
it should have been

```
 while (j <= high)
```

instead of

```
(j < high)
```